# Swashbuckle won't load resources

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I have a .NET MVC application that includes a web service.
I have added Swashbuckle to the web service project and on my local machine everything works fine.

When I move the code to our TEST environment I begin to get 404 errors randomly for the various javascript and CSS libraries.
Sometimes the swagger/ui/index page itself throws a 404.  Sometimes everything loads.

[image]

I've thought about downloading all of these files and placing them in my project for Swagger to use, but based on what I've read, and the way my local environment works, it doesn't seem like that's the way swashbuckle is designed to work, so I'm at a loss.

I have very limited access to the TEST environment so any server configuration will be an issue.  My hope is that swagger.config file can be updated to make everything play nice.

Comment: The fact that on ***local machine everything works fine*** points to something going on with your TEST environment, I have used it on multiple environments and never had any issues, here is my tests project on Azure: http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my TFS build server was NOT overwriting the previous build which led to differences between my load balanced servers and files that were not being updated with changes as I tried to get Swashbuckle to work.